# Multiple Animations in the Same Model

Tags: animation

I am having a model with two hands that I am trying to navigate. I created one of the moves that I want, then in the action editor I clicked the 'F' button. Created a new action and tried to do changes in the timeline but they affect the previous action as well.

Is there a way to modify the actions independently of one another?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mean multiple animation layers (i.e. you animate a walk cycle, then animate different hand movement on top), then no. Blender currently doesn't support that.

Answer (score 3):

The **F** button is just for making a Fake user to avoid the non-user data being removed after closing.

To make a duplication based on current action data, you need to click the number button next to it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it still messes up my original action. I have the file here if you feel like checking it out:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqw66p1qijyr7t8/Go-Today-Backup.blend
Basically I have done the 'today' action and now I would like to create a new one, totally different, but everytime I create it and clear the timeline it make changes to 'today' as well.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you describe the detailed steps on how you inserted keyframe to the new action?

Comment: I think my confusion comes from the fact that it uses 2 separate actions for the different hands. I started all over again and when I moved the second hand it automatically created a new action in the Action Editor. Is that how it is supposed to be?

Comment: @user43051 You could use a single action for both hands this would require different keys for each hand, alternatively you could use two actions with each having only keys for one hand (x-flipped).

Answer (score 0):

to make another action you create your first animation make the fake user "little F button" then when your all done with the first action and ready to start the second action, hit the X button to remove that first action from being edited the X will not delete your action you created just unload it from the action editor for editing, then hit the plus again and there you go 2 seperate actions